# Cannot load drawable in image view Android Studio

Tags: android

I am trying to capture a url from a EditText, download the image with that url and set it to an ImageView. I don't know why but it doesn't show any image when I run the program. If this helps it returns a exception: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

This is my main code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUolN.png)

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Comment: meaning the image need to be downloaded on a background thread maybe an `Executor`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. A good practice that will facilitate for people who want to help solve your problem is to include the code as text formatted as a code block. Why don't you try?

Comment: Don't worry I solved it changing the ImageView to src instead of srcCompat, and giving permissions to Internet in the Android Manifest of the project.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your Network code off your `UI Thread` or the `Main Thread`. Network Operations are intensive and take some time to complete and end up ***blocking the Main Thread*** thus the exception `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

To get around this you can start a new background thread to run your Network code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //declare drawable as a class variable
    Drawable drawable;

......

onCreate(...) {.... }

buttonPressed(View view) { ...}

public Drawable loadImageFromNet(String url) {

      //lambda for Java 8
        new Thread(() -> {
            // do network operation here
            try {
                InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
                drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exc" + e);
                drawable = null;
            }
        }).start();

        return drawable;
    }
}
```

The other code remains the same and code should work with this test URL:

*https://sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-50kb.jpg*

Cheers ...

Comment: Hello, now there is no Exception. Thank for that. But it doesn't resolve the problem, the image doesn't appear in the app when I put the link and press the button.